# Granting privileges to add events in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, authorization, azure-ad-msal

So I have a React app where I want to ask a user to grant access to their calendar for my app. I did that using Authorisation Code with PKCE flow:

- User clicks a button to `allow access to calendar`
- User goes to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` with params (including the encrypted verification code for PKCE is being passed in)
- User is redirected to Microsoft website to grant privileges for `Calendars.ReadWrite` and `offline_access`
- My backend is being triggered by Microsoft website with a `code` from `Authorisation Code flow`
- My backend triggers `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` to get the `access_token` and `refresh_token` (with the unencrypted verification token for PKCE)
- Backend stores `refresh_token` in a database and uses `access_token` to add an event to user's calendar
- If I want to add an event to user's calendar a few days later, I use `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token` without prompting the user again with Microsoft login screen

I have three questions here:

1. Does this flow actually make sense for such application? Is it done correctly?
2. What is the best and most secure way to store the `refresh_token` in the backend?
3. I do these things with regular HTTP requests. Would it make sense to use `msal` React and JavaScript packages to somehow make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this is a fairly standard approach.
2. The question is much too broad and opinion-based to be answered with any precision.
3. Yes, you should use MSAL. In general avoid reimplementing security protocols as much as possible, and instead rely on reputable, actively supported libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your response! You've calmed me down a little bit. :) As for 2, I thought there are some standardised methods how to deal with that in the most secure way possible. As for 3 - I'm struggling to understand how to effectively utilise the `msal` package in a such distributed between frontend and backend process. Will try. :)